# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I just came across with  this

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in /var/www/html/inc/config/db.php on line 11`

at beginning i thought it was something to do with mysql server, but after hours try and error, i found that error is from PDO, if using mysqli_connect no error at all

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=docker", "root", "tiger"); 


$conn = mysqli_connect("mysql", "root", "tiger", null);
```

I also tried with different databases and even with newly created database

does anyone know why one is working the other does not ? ?

**EDIT**:
I'm using docker-compose to set up environment. 
here is docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./bin/webserver
    container_name: '7.1.x-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links: 
      - mysql
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
      - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
  mysql:
    build: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: '5.7-mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: tiger
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'sc-phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
  redis:
    container_name: 'sc-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  mongo:
    container_name: 'mongodb'
    image: mongo:4.0.12-xenial
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_MONGO_PORT}:27017"
    volumes: 
      - ${MONGO_DATA_DIR-./data/mongodb}:/data/db
      - ${MONGO_LOG_DIR-./logs/mongodb/mongod.log}:/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
      - ${MONGO_CONF-./config/mongodb/mongod.conf}:/etc/mongod.conf
```

Comment: `mysql` works for the host name with `mysqli`?

Comment: do u mean localhost? if i change 127.0.0.1 to localhost, pdo gives no file error

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why the connection was not working, it was because the connection was trying to connect to port 8888. when it needed to connect to port 8889.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=docker", "root", "tiger");
```

**To find a listener on a port, do this:**

```
netstat -tln
```

You should see a line that looks like this if MySQL is indeed listening on that port.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306              0.0.0.0:*
```

Port 3306 is MySql's default port.

If you want to know the **port number of your local host on which Mysql** is running you can use this query on MySQL Command line client --

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';


mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It will give you the port number on which MySQL is running.

Comment: thanks for the input, my mysql is running on 3306 for sure i did run SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port'; it confirms it. i changed my original post

Comment: Your PDO connection is not working right? have you tried with port which I mentioned in answer.

Comment: yes, my pdo does not work, i added port=3306, still not working